# Efficient storage and retrieval of 2D Arrays with additional date information

Tags: c#, database, storage, bigdata

I´m writing an C# assembly , which should store and retrieve time-based data, whereupon the data consist of 2D double arrays with dimensions of 500 x 2000.

Every 10 - 100 seconds, I´m getting a set of data which should be stored for ~ 2 years.
Retrieving should be fast enough to get a set of ~ 5000 arrays within the seconds.

In addition, data which is for example older than 6 months should be in a way deleted, that only one array every hour is available.

Now there are several possibilities which I checked already out:

- "classic" database e.g. MS SQL. I´m creating a database structure, which stores the arrays seperate from the timedata, so I can querying the timedata and get only the arrays I really need. Advantage is a very good handling (insert / delete / select) of the data.
  Problem is, you need some level of maintenance for the database, which I can´t guarantee at any time.
- key-value database e.g. REDIS. Runs well, (must serialize + zip the arrays), but my I´m afraid that isn´t the right thing for this sort of storage because of the array size. Other thing is, it should be a persistent storage and not only available in memory.

Does anybody know other possibilites?

Comment: 5000 times a double array of size 500x2000 is a total of nearly 40 gigabytes if data. Are you sure about those figures? Getting a set of 5000 arrays of that size within seconds is not achievable...

Comment: It should be around 20 GB (4 bytes * 500 * 2000 * 5000) but you´re right - it´s quite a lot. I´ve serialized the array per soap formatter (size as txt file ~ 17 MB and gzipped it - size now ~ 1 MB). Problem is the huge cpu utilization to unzip 5000 arrays...phew

Comment: Note that doubles are 8 bytes, not 4 bytes! However, if it's compressing that much it seems to indicate that many of the values are the same - is that the case?

Comment: Right, doubles are 8 byte, my bad. I´ve filled the arrays for testing with randoms between 0 and 1000. Later, the real values are in this range.

Comment: No the CPU to unzip 20GB is negligible compared to the Network Latency.  Irrespective of DB issues, this will not be possible without an amazing LAN, and it will never be achievable over a WAN.

Comment: I've worked with time based data for some systems and we used PI http://www.osisoft.com as the database

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the consumer of the data will need it sequentially. If it is for processing or viewing, there will probably be no need to have all the arrays at once. Maybe you could implement a sort of streaming of the arrays.
You could do this by:

- storing them in the File system, and reading and sending the files one by one. You could hold the index to the files in an SQL database, in which the timestamps are a clustered primary index.
- Using a database (SQL is fine) in which you hold your arrays indexed and ordered by timestamp, and holding the arrays as blob data. This could facilitate quick ordered reads.